# kubectl Secret - passing service account ( json ) file in ansible k8s module

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, k8s-serviceaccount

Am trying to use kubernetes ansible module for creating the kubectl secret, below is my command

```
kubectl create secret generic -n default test --from-file=gcp=serviceaccount.json
```

Do we have any way to pass service account json file(--from-file=gcp=serviceaccount.json) in Ansible k8s module,

how to pass this --from-file in the below module?

```
- name: CREATE SECRET
    k8s:
      state: present
      definition: 
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        type: Opaque             
        metadata:
          name: test
          namespace: default     
        data:
         ?? : ??
```

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using and how did you setup your cluster (cloud solution or bare metal)?

Comment: You could try `kubectl describe secret`, and use the `data` as shown in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am able to resolve the issue with **stringData** option.

Ive passed the content of the file with stringData option

```
- name: CREATE SECRET
    k8s:
      state: present
      definition: 
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        type: Opaque             
        metadata:
          name: test
          namespace: default     
        stringData:
          content of the file
```